# Use bash to remove strings between guard characters from text file

Tags: bash

I have a long text file that reads like:

```
where the last element of :math:`\pmb{x}_i\in\mathbf{R}^{p}` is 1 and
the first :math:`p-1` elements of :math:`\pmb{x_i}` and
```

I would like to replace all strings that between `:math:` and "`" by white spaces. For example, the text above should become:

```
where the last element of is 1 and
the first  elements of  and
```

I tried this:

```
sed $'/end/ {r exceptions\n} ; /:math:/,/`/ {d}' input_text.text > output_text.text
```

but this removes the whole line containing the guard strings. I just want to remove what is between the guard strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`` sed -E 's/:math:`[^`]*`//g' ``

Given your input, as output I get

`where the last element of is 1 and the first elements of and`

It's worth noting that this assumes that the ` character cannot be used inside the :math: tag.

Comment: OP wants to remove `:math:`; I think it should be `s/:math:`[^`]*`//g`

Comment: Can we remove the guard characters as well?? I mean perhaps a second command to get rid of the many ":math:``" left?

Comment: This also assumes the construct can't span multiple lines. Also, for GNU sed you need `-r`.

Comment: Edited the answer, sorry about that.  Whatever you want to replace the :math: blocks with should go between the second `//` in the sed command; essentially the format is `s/find/replace/g` (the `g` is "find as many times as it occurs in the lines).

Comment: To make it handle multiline :math: expressions like 4ae1e1 suggested, you could easily do something horrible like `tr '\n' '_' | sed '...' | tr '_' '\n'` where `_` can be replaced by some character that you know doesn't exist in the document.  This is not the cleanest way to do things, but if someone's holding a gun to your head, it should do the trick.